# Converge and "Verb Confusion"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

MS Word has been complaining of a grammatical *Word Confusion* error when I use *converge*.

Here's my sentence:

> Managers had converged the thousands of ideas into a handful of big ideas.

If I drop *the* from the sentence Word does not find any error. Also, if I exchange *converged* for *combined* Word is happy. However, I guess what I would like to say with *converge* is a mix of *merged* and *combined*.

Is that my confusion or is there a better word?

Comment: Pro tip: Using MS Word's grammar checker is a rookie move.

Comment: What you would like to say with "converge" and the normal definitions of "converge" do not really match. Maybe you should just use "combined".

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇  *Combining* ideas takes less effort than to *converge* them -- they're managers, you see.

Comment: The transitive use of converge sounds a little weird to me. Maybe MSWord has some rule about that (even though dictionaries say it can be used that way (thanks @Kris)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that MS Word is correct and that you should change the word to **merged** or, as you've suggested, **combined**. **Converged** is word unto itself and isn't a combination of **combined** and **merged**. This is what the Online Etymological Dictionary says:

> converge (v.) 1690s, from L.L. convergere "to incline together" from com- "together" (see com-) + vergere "to bend" (see verge (v.)). Related: Converged; converging.

Comment: I do realize its not a combination of those words, strictly speaking. But your dictionary definition seems to fit what I'm trying to say better than either merged or combined.

Comment: I think that the transitive use of _converged_ is a misusage. Things converge, people don't converge things. Couldn't find transitive use in BNC or COCA. It's not natural American English.

Comment: @Stoney, the problem is that "converge" is not a transitive verb. You may say that "ideas converge (by themselves)", but you cannot say "I converged these ideas".

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that things can converge but you cannot converge them. Maybe a better fitting word would be "coalesced." The sentence is a little clumsily put together anyhow, even if it was valid for managers to converge things. Was there any outstanding idea that emerged or something else a little more exciting than unknown ideas converging?

Comment: I doubt "coalesced" would be understood by my intended audience and perhaps the same is true for "converged". Basically, thousands of independently developed overlapping ideas were gathered. Then the managers took the ideas, used software to sort them into clusters of related ideas. They then looked at the clusters manually, assessed what was interesting and created 30 broad ideas for further discussion and development. - So loads of converging going on...

Comment: Maybe _synthesized_?

Comment: brainstorming or innovation assisted by high tech conputing or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the word:

> [***distilled (distill)***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/distill) : *4. To separate or extract the essential elements of*

which connotes more effort and process than does a simple combination.

Answer (score 0):

The real complaint of Word was that you placed a noun immediately after the verb.

You may try

> "Managers had converged **all of** the thousands of ideas into a handful of big ideas."

which resolves the issue.

Any other structural change (between verb and noun) should also do the trick.

Comment: I know the "grammarian" will never show up to comment about his down vote. Lol.